# Where to put await in this function?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

```
 protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
       base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

       var content = (Content) Application.Current.Resources["NavigationParam"];

       titleName.Text = content.title;
       var uri = new Uri(content.url, UriKind.Absolute);
       imageShow.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
 }
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Column Warning  CS1998  This
>   async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
>   Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls,
>   or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background
>   thread.   ImageParser C:\Users\Johny\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ImageParser\ImdbSample\ItemView.xaml.cs 26  41

Comment: Are you doing any asynchronous work in this method at all? Putting the `async` modifier on a method does not make anything magically run in parallel. If that is your train of thought, then nowhere.

Comment: I am parsing images from devianart.com to my windows phone app. I download images in background

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async-await`. I suggest your read ["Parallel Programming in .NET"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693(v=vs.110).aspx), I think that's what you're after.

Comment: The method you're writing can't be async: since you need to change titleName and imageShow.Source, this code must be executed before page render so must be into page lifecycle. Async methods are used for long activities that must not stop page lifecycle (sending email or other operations that don't effect page structure)

Answer (score 2):

You are not awaiting any asynchronous operations (by using the `await` operator) inside the body of the method, therefore the `async` keyword in your method definition is not necessary. Just delete it and the warning will go away.

This will not change your method's semantics. As the warning message clearly states, it already runs synchronously anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`BitmapImage` automatically downloads images asynchronously - there is no need for you to do anything extra. Remove the `async` keyword and the warning will go away.

If you absolutely must await the image download before doing anything else, here is some code to show you how.

```
// create a task source that we can await on later
TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

titleName.Text = content.title;

// create an image
var image = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

// subscribe to the images download complete events - set results to true or false depending on if the download finish ok.
image.DownloadCompleted += (sender, args) => taskSource.TrySetResult(true);
                image.DownloadFailed += (sender, args) => taskSource.TrySetResult(false);

// set the uri to start the download
image.UriSource = new Uri(content.url, UriKind.Absolute);

// await the task to extract the result    
bool wasDownloadSuccessful = await taskSource.Task;
```